# Combine 2 SQL queries to get Distinct values from one column and biggest from second

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
Country Year
100 201313
100 201212
101 201314
101 201213
101 201112
102 201313
102 201212
103 201313
103 201212
104 201313
104 201212
```

I need a query that delivers just one country and just the greatest value of year, for example:

```
Country Year
100 201313
101 201314
102 201313
103 201313
104 201313
```

My solution until now is to make a first query in which I get the Distinct Countries, and then in a while, another query to get the years...

```
$resOne = $mysqli->query("SELECT DISTINCT Country from Table ORDER BY Country ASC");
while ($obj = $resOne->fetch_object()){
    $resTwo = $mysqli->query("SELECT Country, Year from Table WHERE Country = $resOne->Country ORDER BY Country ASC LIMIT 1")->fetch_object();
    echo $resTwo->Country $resTwo->Year;
}
```

**Question:** Is it someway possible to deliver this result with just one query?

Thanks for reading and answering.

**UPDATE**

The scripts on the answers from user2989408 and Drew is good and working, but when I join the table with another one I´m not getting the correct data.

Here's a fiddle to my DB sample and script: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31613/1/0

How can I make that the Description row shows the description from MAX(s.Year)? For instance, the first row in the fiddle should show "France newest 201314".

Comment: Can I start by asking why are you storing your Year in this fashion?

Comment: It's for a football / soccer site. Depending on the country the leagues can go from 2013/14 or just 2013 or have two competitions in the same year... so 201314 = 2013/14, 201313 = 2013, 201301 = first season of 2013 and 201302 = second season of 2013.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more efficient to do those sort of conversions at display instead of having to parse out those two values?

Comment: At display I'm displaying the correct strings e.g. "2013/14" instead of "201314". The question was for doing the index where I display all countries and their most recent league. For instance to display: Spain Liga BBVA 2013/14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query:

[SQLfiddleexample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31613/5)

```
SELECT c.Name, s.Description, s.Year
FROM countries c 
JOIN seasons s 
  ON c.Id=s.Id
LEFT JOIN seasons s2 
  ON s.ID = s2.ID
  AND s2.Year > s.Year
WHERE s2.id is null
ORDER BY c.Name ASC
```

Result:

```
|        NAME | DESCRIPTION |   YEAR |
|-------------|-------------|--------|
|      France |      newest | 201314 |
|     Germany |         new | 201212 |
|       Italy |         new | 201313 |
| Netherlands |      newest | 201313 |
|       Spain |         new | 201313 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Query should be

```
SELECT t.Country, MAX(t.Year)
FROM Table t
GROUP BY t.Country
ORDER BY t.Country ASC
```

**EDIT:** After the updated requirement, to SELECT other info the query can be modified as follows to work.

```
SELECT c.Name, s.Description, s.Year 
FROM
    (
        SELECT s.id as id, MAX(s.Year) as Max
        FROM seasons s
        GROUP BY s.Id
    ) as X
    JOIN countries c ON c.Id = X.Id
    JOIN seasons s ON s.id = X.id AND X.Max = s.Year
ORDER BY c.Name ASC
```

A sub query can also be used to select the required info as follows.

```
SELECT c.Name,
    (SELECT s1.Description 
         FROM seasons s1 WHERE s1.id = X.id AND X.Max = s1.Year) as Description, 
    X.Max as Year
FROM
    (
        SELECT s.id as id, MAX(s.Year) as Max
        FROM seasons s
        GROUP BY s.Id
    ) as X
    JOIN countries c ON c.Id = X.Id
ORDER BY c.Name ASC
```

Essentially there is more than one way to get the info you need if you understand how `GROUP BY` works.

Comment: The script you wrote is good and working, but when I join the table with another one I´m not getting the correct data. See [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31613/1/0) How can I make that the Description row shows the description from MAX(s.Year)? For instance, the first row in the fiddle should show "France newest 201314"

Comment: @Emmanuel The description has to be selected separately using another `JOIN` AS shown [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31613/13) or using a sub query. I am guessing you want to select only the Country's Name and Description for the latest season.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT         Country, 
               Max(Year) 
FROM   Table 
GROUP  BY Country
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not needed.